# Есть ли способ сократить код?

Tags: java, android, оптимизация

Android Studio выдает предупреждение (длина метода = 20), что нижеследующий метод onNavigationItemSelected (длина = 21) содержит длинный код. Есть ли способ сократить код?

```
@Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.nav_catalog) {
      runActivity(CatalogActivity.class);
      return false;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_new_chapters) {
      runFragment(NewChaptersFragment.class.getName());
    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_bookmarks) {
      runFragment(BookmarksFragment.class.getName());
    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_search) {
      runFragment(SearchFragment.class.getName());
    } else if (itemId == R.id.navigationFavoritesUser) {
      runFragmentUserTab(ParserUserTab.FAVOURITES);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.navigationWantToReadUser) {
      runFragmentUserTab(ParserUserTab.I_WANT_TO_READ);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.navigationTheListReadUser) {
      runFragmentUserTab(ParserUserTab.LIST_OF_READ);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.navigationNewChapterUser) {
      runFragmentUserTab(ParserUserTab.NOVELTIES_FOR_ME);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.navigationBookmarksUser) {
      runFragmentUserTab(ParserUserTab.BOOKMARKS);
    }
    return true;
  }

@Override public void runFragment(String nameClassFragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_main, Fragment.instantiate(this, nameClassFragment),
            nameClassFragment)
        .commit();
  }

@Override public void runFragmentUserTab(int tab) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_main, UserTabFragment.newInstance(tab),
            UserTabFragment.class.getName())
        .commit();
  }
```

Comment: не пробовал использовать case?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Ну короче со switch-case точно не станет. Там ещё придётся `break` для каждого условия добавлять. @Иван а что это за предупреждение? Никогда не видел, чтобы студия проверяла длину методов

Comment: А зачем сокращать код?

Comment: @eugeneek, по умолчанию она отключена. Включить можно в настройке: Setting - Editor - Inspections - строка "Overly long method". Там можно задать желаемую максимальную длину метода. И вывести как предупреждение или как ошибку или т.д.

Comment: @Geri4, Код в методе некрасиво читается. Слишком много дублирующих слов.

Comment: Зато сразу понятно, что там происходит. Не вижу смысла сокращать этот конкретный код. Можно конечно нагородить кучу доп методов и классов и уместить код в 5 строк, но читаемость от этого станет только хуже

Comment: @Иван лучше много дублирующих слов и с полувзгляда понятный код, нежели максимально краткий, но тот который что бы понять нужно долго вглядываться и вспоминать что там делается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создайте статичную `Map<Integer, String> mFragments`.
2. Инициализируйте где-то при старте.
3. Тогда метод `onNavigationItemSelected` будет таким:

   ```
   @Override 
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       int itemId = item.getItemId();
       if (itemId == R.id.nav_catalog) {
         runActivity(CatalogActivity.class);
         return false;
       } else {
         if(mFragments.containsKey(itemId) {
            runFragmentUserTab(mFragments.get(itemId));
         }
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```